# AllocConsole error codes

Tags: c++, windows, console

What error codes can a failed call to [AllocConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) generate? On the MSDN website it says `If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.` But I see no place saying what kinds of errors it can generate.

Comment: A full list of system error codes is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I meant the errors that can result from AllocConsole. Is the only thing that can make that function fail a console already existing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In most system calls, there is a rather long list of "possible failure scenarios", and that means that you get a large number of possible error codes. For example, some resource in the OS may be full (I expect there is a list of consoles in the OS somewhere, and if that list is full and/or can't be grown, there is some error for that). The Console also needs to have memory as a buffer for the text content, as well as a graphical output buffer (to avoid having to draw every character every time the screen is refreshed) - both of these lead to at least two distinct errors (out of memory, out of graphics memory, and possibly "no way to create a handle for the graphics resource").

A different category of possible errors are permission based ones - maybe your process (based on the user being logged in) doesn't have enough permissions to create a console.

I'm pretty sure the list of actually possible errors is much greater than that.

In summary, don't expect that the errors you can get from a function is limited - if you are interested in a particular set of error codes, then check for those, and do something sane if it isn't one of those. Don't expect that you can't get any other error code.